# How am I supposed to build an emscripten project with the stb_image headers?

Tags: c, linker, header, emscripten

I have a webassembly project, and I want to build it with emscripten.

I cloned the [stbi image header files](https://github.com/nothings/stb) in my project and then tried to compile everything.

My `main.c` looks like that:

```
#include "stb_image.h"
#include <emscripten.h>

...

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void my_func(int test) {
    // I need some functions from stbi image
    stbi_load_from_memory(...)
};
```

So the first thing I tried was `emcc main.c`

I get this first error:

```
error: undefined symbol: stbi_write_jpg_to_func (referenced by top-level compiled C/C++ code)
warning: Link with `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED` to get more information on undefined symbols
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
warning: _stbi_write_jpg_to_func may need to be added to EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS if it arrives from a system library
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
```

Then I tried to compile the libraries first, as mentioned in [the docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Building-Projects.html#using-libraries)

First command `emcc stb_image.h main.c -c`, I get warnings.

```
clang-11: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
```

And when I try to use the result of that it always fails.

And if I do it the other way arround: `emcc main.c stb_image.h -c` this time I get an error:

```
emcc: error: cannot mix precompile headers with non-header inputs: ['main.c', 'stb_image.h'] : main.c
```

So I have no idea what I can do to compile it properly.

I don't know much about gcc, linking and emcc:

How does my makefile have to look like to build that ?

Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` before you include the header, like this:

```c
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
```

Unlike most libraries out there, the STB headers are (usually) directly compiled within your project's source code; no linking required.
Most other stb headers require you to define special macros before you include them. Read the documentation (at the top of the header files) to know which macro to define.